# How to create a global array in laravel controller classes?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, web, model-view-controller

I want to create a global array inside a controller class in laravel. I searched and explored many resources but couldn't find a proper answer. I want that array to be accessible by all the methods in that controller. Currently I have tried this :

`public  $members=array(1,2);` Global variable

```
`global $members;`  //Inside function
```

`echo $members[0];`  //Inside function

I tried to access the data in the array in the function but got a null exception.Please help me out.

Comment: You should study Object Oriented Programming before diving into Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `$this` keyword.

```
class x extends Controller {

     public  $members = array(1,2);

     public function myAction(){
          echo $this->members[0];
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro you helped out I was stuck in this for nearly two days !!!

Comment: @RishdhiMuhammed your'e welcome. I highly recommend  to read the PHP and the Laravel documentions at least one time. That will do a lot of help. Also don't forget to choose answers in the StackOverflow